# Reference primary key from many-to-many table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design

I have 2 tables: `Student` and `Class` with `many-to-many` relationship through `Student_Class(StudentID, ClassID) table.`

I also need table `Payment(StudentID, ClassID, Fee...)` and `Request(StudentID, ClassID, Request,...).`

Should I create Student_Class table like above or like this: `(StudentClassID,StudentID, ClassID)` then remove 2 PKs in `Payment` and `Request` with new PK:  `StudentClassID`? Which one is better and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are probably two things to consider in this answer, one is the technical database side (stuff like performance, storage and integrity), and the other is a business question.

So, just to restate, the following are given:

```
Student (StudentID, ...)
Class (ClassID, ...)
```

And there are currently two options for the other tables:

*A*

```
Student_Class (StudentID, ClassID, ...)
Payment (StudentID, ClassID, Fee, ...)
Request (StudentID, ClassID, Request, ...)
```

*B*

```
Student_Class (Student_ClassID, StudentID, ClassID, ...)
Payment (Student_ClassID, Fee, ...)
Request (Student_ClassID, Request, ...)
```

The second scheme would use less storage (+), probably have slightly lower performance for queries (-) and be more convoluted (-).

Option B makes things tricky if the business ever wants to track a student's payments or requests that are not associated with a class (-).

In most cases, I'd probably recommend option A.